# How to disable scrolling behind a modal mask on iPad?

Tags: javascript, css, ios5

I'm creating a web application that should work also on iPad. Now with iOS 5 even the scrolling works OK. But my problem is that if I have a modal window, the scrolling behind the modal mask is enabled, even if other events are disabled. Does anybody know how I can switch off the scrolling behind the modal mask?

Example:

The grid that has scrolling enabled:

```
.z-grid{
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The modal mask:

```
.z-modal-mask {
   background:#E0E1E3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
   height:100%;
   left:0;
   opacity:0.6;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   z-index:30000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The element `z-grid` needs to have position active to enable z-index. Try either `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`. I can't say exactly which one as I can't see your markup :)

```
.z-grid{
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative; /*or absolute*/
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, with position: relative; but it doesn't solve my problem, maybe is an iOS5 bug. Because, every other action doesn't work, only the scrolling works behind the modal mask. If I'm not using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; the scrolling is disabled, but I don't see the scrollbar anymore.

Comment: So you want to disable the scroll of the element behind the mask? I understand that the webkit-overflow-scrollbar should be disabled when the modal mask is available. MAybe you can use a js to change the overflow when the modal window is active?

Comment: Yes, I think that this is what I need to do. I thought that maybe somebody solved this by CSS. Thanks, anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through a lot of answers regarding disabling scrolling of body on iPads behind the modal, and none have been found to be suitable particularly when having a scrollable div on the modal, I found a combination of [this javascript logic from another SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244680/41211) plus then unattaching the event handler on popup close did the trick.

On popup/dialog open:

```
//uses document because document will be topmost level in bubbling
$(document).on('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
//uses body because jquery on events are called off of the element they are
//added to, so bubbling would not work if we used document instead.
$('body').on('touchstart', '.scrollable', function (e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
        e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
    } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
        e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
    }
});
//prevents preventDefault from being called on document if it sees a scrollable div
$('body').on('touchmove', '.scrollable', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

On popup/dialog close:

```
$(document).off('touchmove');
$('body').off('touchstart', '.scrollable');
$('body').off('touchmove', '.scrollable');
```

The mentions of `scrollable` above just let elements you do require scrolling be exempt from the logic if the element has that css class set.

In my case, I had a scrollable div inside my popup, causing all sorts of issues, so to disable background scrolling but still allow to scroll within the dialog scrollable div, make sure you add a `scrollable` class to your scrollable div so it is ignored.