# Jquery check if any parent div have scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if any parent div have scroll bar in jQuery but I can't find any good example.
Here is my code:-

```
  <div>
     <div class="heading">
        <div class="visitor_profile">
            <div class="visitor_input_con">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to check if any parent of `.visitor_input_con` has scroll bar here is my jquery code:-

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
    return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
  }
})(jQuery);

$('.visitor_input_con').hasScrollBar();
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could filter out parents, e.g:

```
if($('.visitor_input_con').parents().filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasScrollBar();
}).length)
```