# Prevent page scroll but allow element with overflow scroll to scroll JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a page in jquery mobile, I want to prevent the page from scrolling but allow the user to scroll an element on the page that has overflow set to scroll. Should be noted that the reason I need this is because the page length will vary slightly, beyond 100% on some different devices.

```
<div data-role="page" id="noscroll>
    <div data-role="content">
         <div class="scrollable">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried something like this but obviously this prevents the scrollable element from responding to the touchmove event.

```
$('#noscroll').on('touchmove', function(){
      e.preventDefault();
      });
```

Comment: **[This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132630/how-to-prevent-document-scrolling-but-allow-scrolling-inside-div-elements-on-web)**  and **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling)** might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of approach :

```
$('*:not(.scrollable)').on('scroll touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

not tested but should be a start to find the correct way to do what you want.