# Scroll with Phonegap + jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, scroll, swipe

I hace a problem with my app, made (or making) with Phonegap Cordova + jQuery Mobile.
I try the app with my iPad, but only with iPhone version.

Y change the UIWebViewBounce directive to false in config.xml because the Safari Scroll . But I have a view with a list. If I touch an swipe to up (not down, only up) the view scrolls top a few pixels, same pixels than the iOS topbar (the bar with the hour, battery, etc).

I try with this JS code:

```
document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

But then, the scroll of my views not work neither, although they have the scrollable class.

I've tried this:

```
document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
var touchstart = e.pageY;
if(touchstart < 35) {
    e.preventDefault();
}};
```

And when I swipe up from the header it works, the app does not scroll, OK, but if I scroll to the bottom of the list, the last element, and I continue scrolling down (swipping up), the app do that shit with the header, only that pixels, and then stop scrolling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix.
In this post:

[iOS Safari – How to disable overscroll but allow scrollable divs to scroll normally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238084/ios-safari-how-to-disable-overscroll-but-allow-scrollable-divs-to-scroll-norma)

The second answer, from Tyler Dodge