# Ipad iOS inconsistent scrolling: disable body scroll but allow scroll on certain elements

Tags: javascript, ios, css

On my site I have scrollable menus and content inside a fixed page. Often upon loading the page these elements scroll without issue. But then when the body/html elements are grabbed/focused on the page it just bounces around and the scrollable elements become unscrollable. Sometimes the body/html are automatically focused on. This behaviour can be fixed by clicking something within the scrollable elements thereby adjusting the focus.

I'm wondering if there's a way to check what element is currently active/grabbed/focused/whatever and if it's the body/html changing it to the content.

Comment: Please provide some source code, maybe html page. It is hard to understand what caused some problem.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander I didn't add code because there are way too many considerations that could be affecting my issue. I figured it out though... Using `preventDefault` on a `touchmove` event listener for body/html and then `stopPropagation` on `touchmove` for all the scrollable elements fixes the issue. See my answer if you're interested. I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while and the solution is incredibly useful for controlling scroll behaviour on touch devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Safari – How to disable overscroll but allow scrollable divs to scroll normally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238084/ios-safari-how-to-disable-overscroll-but-allow-scrollable-divs-to-scroll-norma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by disabling scrolling on all elements with `preventDefault` and allowing it on certain elements with `stopPropagation`

I'm using Sizzle (JQuery's selector engine) to select DOM elements. You can just replace the $ selectors with standard JS selection (`document.getElementById` etc.), but I'd highly recommend using Sizzle if you don't use jQuery.

prevent scroll on all elements:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()}, false);
$('body')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()}, false);
```

allow scroll for certain elements:

```
$('#SCROLLABLE_DIV')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){e.stopPropagation()}, false);
```

Comment: As usual  e.preventDefault() rescues situation

Answer (score 0):

**NEWEST UPDATE** first: I canceled my own attempts to find a solution, as I came around a working example [here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894997) using iNoBounce.js.
Thus this is my last edit here on this post.

And hereby I provide my [working example](http://ddlab.de/stackoverflow/no-bounce-using-iNoBounce-js/).

The old version of my example you'll still find here
[how to prevent body scrolling on mobile devices](http://ddlab.de/stackoverflow/how-to-prevent-body-scrolling-on-mobile-devices/)