# `webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` creates bouncing on iOS

Tags: ios, css, cordova

I need a smooth scrolling for my app, so I added `webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

Unfortunately, now the content bounces when I pull down the view. 
Is there a fix for it or another property that I can use to have the same scrolling smooth behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894997/prevent-ios-bounce-without-disabling-scroll-ability

Comment: It does not solve my problem. That's because the `webkit-overflow-scrolling` attribute produces the bouncing. When I delete it, the bouncing is away. But I need the lazy scrolling.