# Any known javascript or css that causes Chrome to not scroll vertically on a MacBook display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a weird issue where my div is not scrolling vertically in Chrome on my MacBook display. If I move the window (without resizing it or anything) to a different display vertical scrolling works. If I scroll horizontally first that "unlocks" the vertical scrolling. Only in Chrome, only on the MacBook display.

I can't share the page here, but I can try to re-produce it with some different content if that is helpful. Thought I would check if it is a known issue first. I have some jquery resizing things going on that might be a lead.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var table_p = $("#table");
    var position = table_p.position();
    var viewheight = $(window).height() - position.top - 10;
    table_p.height(viewheight);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var table_p = $("#table");
        var position = table_p.position();
        var viewheight = $(window).height() - position.top - 10;
        table_p.height(viewheight);
    });
}, 250);
```

Comment: show us the code!!!

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29894997/691711

Comment: @zero298 No, I can't scroll vertically at all (unless scrolling horizontally first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out setting a height in the css for `#table` fixed the problem, even though the height is replaced by js soon after.