# Safari iOS13 - webkit-overflow-scrolling no longer works to disable momentum scrolling

Tags: html, css, ios13, webkit-overflow-scrolling

Prior to ios 13, I was disabling momentum scrolling by setting `webkit-overflow-scrolling` to `auto`. But this property [no longer works in ios 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes) which has caused regression in my webapp and I am experiencing flickering during scrolling(especially around scroll edges) in my webpage due to momentum scrolling.

Please suggest some way to turn off the momentum scrolling.

Comment: Inserted image instead of using video link.

Comment: Duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684546/css-disable-bounce-effect-for-scroll-on-ios-13

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Disable bounce effect for scroll on iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684546/css-disable-bounce-effect-for-scroll-on-ios-13)