# overflow hidden does not lock scroll in safari browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react, I'm trying to lock scroll on body so I applied `overflow:hidden` on `<body>` and it works on all browser except safari.

I also tried `positoin:fixed`. it locks the scroll but does not restore scroll position.

**question:** how can I lock scroll of `body` on iOS safari?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193062/how-to-disable-scrolling-on-body-in-ios-13-safari-when-saved-as-pwa-to-the-home

Answer (score -1):

"Overflow: hidden" through "v" in "oWerflow".
Look on position: relative.