# iPhone Safari smooth scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

**How do I get rid of this black area that appears when I scroll up in the iPhone Safari without disabling the [smooth scroll](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-smooth-scroll-links/)?**

[image]

I tried [NoBounce js](https://github.com/timbartsch/no-bounce), but it is not working for me.

I also tried this CSS solution (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895108/3965675)):

```
html {
    height  : 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    height  : 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

But this disabled the smooth scroll function and also it makes the iphone Safari footer sticky as in the below GIF:
[image]

Comment: Add [`scroll-behavior: smooth;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior).

Comment: Should I add this css `body` element?

Comment: Add to `html{scroll-behavior: smooth;}`

Comment: `scroll-behavior` is not supported in Safari: https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Comment: Then , [this might helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011205/is-there-a-safari-equivalent-for-scroll-behavior-smooth/56011281)