# How to disable swiping outside the window when viewing on phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building a hybrid app amd test viewing it in safari on my phone. I have a fixed header and footer in my pages. When I am scrolled down (or at the top) and try to scroll further, the content sort of swipes outside the view. How can I disable this?

Comment: You want to prevent overscroll. There is no easy way, that I know, to do this. This thread could be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238084/ios-safari-how-to-disable-overscroll-but-allow-scrollable-divs-to-scroll-norma

Comment: Will have a look. Do you know whether overscroll is also a problem when you deploy the app through Phonegap, and thus files are installed locally?