# iOS: Prevent overscrolling on top

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad, scroll

I am creating a web app for iPads. For that I would like to prevent overscrolling on the top of the page.

The closest solution I've found was this: [iOS Safari – How to disable overscroll but allow scrollable divs to scroll normally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238084/ios-safari-how-to-disable-overscroll-but-allow-scrollable-divs-to-scroll-norma)
But I seem to have a little bit more difficult case.
The snippet basically disables all scrolling except for `.scrollable` elements. I need it to only block scrolling upwards, if the top of the page is hit, and only prevent scrolling on the body.